# Get users by meta_key and array of meta_values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to query WP users with meta_key and have one or more meta_value within an array. This array is generated from new WP_Query. I'm querying post using $args to get post IDs.

print_r ($query->posts) shows the correct array: 
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 101 [2] => 102 [3] => 103 )

Now I'm trying to get users using this array as meta_value.
I have a user with my_key and 102 and 103 saved as user meta. print_r ($my_key) shows the correct user meta array: 
Array ( [0] => 102 [1] => 103 )

```
$user_args = array(
   'meta_query' => array(
      array(
         'key'  => 'my_key',
         'value' => $query->posts,
         'type' => 'numeric',
         'compare' => 'IN'
         )
       ),
    ); 
$users = get_users( $user_args );
```

But no users are being queried... can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

And scroll down to "Custom Field Parameters"

i guess that helps

Comment: Thanks but that is where I got the above from.

Comment: Nope not working either, could it be that they are numbers?